# JMSserializer deserialize related Doctrine Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, jms-serializer

I have json like this:

```
"relatedCollection": [
  {
     id:1,
     name: "something",
     country: {
           id:1
          }
  },
    {
     id:2,
     name: "something 2",
     country: {
           id:1
          }
  }

]
```

Two related items that have a common country that exists in database. If I deserialize with JMSserializer, and **it creates a two different instances of COUNTRY entity**.

When you apply merge with doctrine, set properly country to "something", but not to "something 2". So the result after save is:

```
"relatedCollection": [
  {
     id:1,
     name: "something",
     country: {
           id:1
          }
  },
    {
     id:2,
     name: "something 2",
     country: null
  }

]
```

For Doctrine there are two different entities called Country that are detached. And doctrine attach the first and save it properly but not the second.

This only happens with relations ManyToOne, when you merge a collection with the same related entity id.
If you save country 1 and country 2, there'is no repeated country, so save property.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS Serializer just does the object deserialization, it does not handles the doctrine object for you.

You have to do any kind of merge, cascade merge, for example

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

You can write a deserialization Listener\Subscriber to do auto-merge for you automatically

Comment: Thanks, I didn't underestand how doctrine manages entities, but I solved doing merge and setting cascade merge.

Comment: Deserialized entity is a usual state while working with doctrine entities. These kind of entities are not attached to the entity manager at the moment of deserialization, so changes are not tracked, relations are not resolved, etc. If you manually persist entity at this sate - it results in a new entity. `merge()` call attaches detached entity to the `em` and allows you to do all usual OOP stuff after